# Not getting the JWT token from the backend in the Headers of the Response

Tags: express, authentication, axios, jwt, token

> I'm sending a token to the front-end (Log In App) when the Login is initiated and token is created ifs the user is registered and sending token using res.header function but when I log the response.headers **I'm getting only content-type (which is default I think) but whenever I try to sign-in from the Postman I get the Token on the headers section.**
>
> This is Code of my express backend server which is creating a token
> and sending it

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let user = {email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password};
  if (validateUser(user)) {
    pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM auth WHERE email = ($1) AND password = crypt(($2), password)',
      [user.email, user.password],
    )
    .then( (results) => {
      if(results.rows.length >= 1) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ name: results.rows[0].name, email: results.rows[0].email }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        console.log(results.rows[0].name + ' Logged In');
        res.header('Authorization', token );
        res.status(200).json({message: "Welcome! " + results.rows[0].name });
      }
    },
    ( error ) => {
      res.status(401).json({message: 'User Not Found'});
    }
   )
  }
  else {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'Invalid Credentials'});
  }
});
```

> In case if the front-end code is required :

```
login() {
            this.axios.post( 'http://localhost:3000/users/login', {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                } )
                .then(
                    ( response ) => {
                        console.log( response.headers );
                        this.$router.push( {path: '/register'} );
                    },
                    ( error ) => {
                        alert( error.response.data.message );
                    }
                )
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: I've tried res.status(200).header(...).end() still nothing works

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header should only be used when sending a request; not during a response. Try instead returning the authorisation in the body of the response:

```
res.status(200).json({message: "Welcome! " + results.rows[0].name,token:token});
```